# Find if part of a string is in another column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a sheet containing the following (lookup) column

```
ABC
DEF
HIJ
```

I have another sheet containing the data

```
ABC123
QWE762
HIJ234
```

I want to look at the first 3 character of the second sheet, and if it matches any cell in the first sheet (same Excel file), output "Y", otherwise, output "N".

So my output should be

```
ABC123 Y
QWE762 N
HIJ234 Y
```

I have

`=IF(MATCH(LEFT(B2,3),A2:A4,0),"Y",N")`

where `B2` is the cell `ABC123` and `A2:A4` is the column in the first sheet. I keep getting the error `#N/A` (Value not available). Why is that?

Comment: (1) Obviously, your formula is missing a quote, between `"Y",` and `N"`. (2) It may be better to say `A$2:A$4` (instead of `A2:A4`) to allow you to drag/fill your formula.  (3) This formula can be expected to evaluate to `#N/A` for the “QWE” row (because that’s what `MATCH` does when it can’t find a match).  Try `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(LEFT(B2,3),A$2:A$4,0)),"N","Y")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MATCH` function returns #NA if there is no match. `IF` tests for true or false, but returns #NA from `MATCH` so the false condition, "N", never happens.

Use `IFNA` to test for the #NA result. Assuming `Sheet1` has the lookup column, this formula in C2 of the second sheet tests the result of the `IF` function. `IF` returns "Y" or #NA, so `IFNA` returns "Y" or "N".

```
=IFNA(IF(MATCH(LEFT(B2,3),Sheet1!$A2:$A4,0),"Y"),"N")
```

Answer (score 1):

The N/A error means that there is no exact match. Double check your data.

Data type is important, too. There may be numbers in one sheet and numbers stored as text in the other. If the lookup range contains numbers, you need to convert the text output from the Left() statement to numbers, for example like

```
 =IF(MATCH(LEFT(B2,3)+0,A2:A4,0),"Y",N")
```